# Can I use alembic autogenerate with Peewee ORM?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, peewee, alembic

I used Alembic with SQL alchemy, and the autogenerate option worked great.
In my new company, we use Peewee as ORM. Is it possible to make Alembic autogenerate work with Peewee as well?

I looked in the docs
https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html
and there were a lot of SQL alchemy mentions, but I couldn't find something that says it will work only on SQL alchemy

Comment: No, Alembic is solely for migrating SQLAlchemy applications.  See https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Peewee has migrations, you just want to write them in python yourself. It's quite easy: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#schema-migrations

Comment: Thanks, @snakecharmerb.
I write them now myself coleifer, I looked for the beloved feature of autogenerating that I used in the last project

Answer (score 2):

To make it clear for future developers that come from Google, **there isn't an option to use autogenerate of alembic for something other than SQLalchemy** right now [7.2021] as you can see in @snakecharmerb comment.

And in the [Docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/index.html)